# Deploy Next.js with Nx program to Amazon Amplify Hosting

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

In a normal Next.js program created with create-next-app and configured with output: standalone, it generates a standalone folder containing a server.js file. This setup allows Amazon Amplify Hosting to serve the Next.js program seamlessly.

However, when using Next.js with Nx, the build structure differs as follows:

```
 - dist/appa/app
  - .next
   - standalone
    - apps/app
     - server.js
```

This structure poses a problem for Amazon Amplify Hosting, as it cannot serve the Next.js application in this configuration.

Is there a way to relocate the server.js file from the apps/app folder to the root directory for the standalone server when building the Next.js app using nx build?